# ZIO 2012: Toy Set

Tags: algorithm

A toy set contains blocks showing the numbers from 1 to 9. There are plenty of blocks
showing each number and blocks showing the same number are indistinguishable. We
want to examine the number of different ways of arranging the blocks in a sequence so
that the displayed numbers add up to a fixed sum.
For example, suppose the sum is 4. There are 8 different arrangements:

1 1 1 1

1 1 2

1 2 1

1 3

2 1 1

2 2

3 1

4

The rows are arranged in dictionary order (that is, as they would appear if they were
listed in dictionary).
In each of the cases below, you are given the desired sum S and a number K. You have
to write down the Kth line when all arrangements that add up to S are written down
as described above. For instance, if S is 4 and K is 5, the answer is 2 1 1. Remember
that S may be large, but the numbers on the blocks are only from 1 to 9.
(a) S = 9, K = 156
 (b) S = 11, K = 881
 (c) S = 14, K = 4583

So basically each case (1111, 112, etc.) also known in maths as a partition of a number, although 112 and 121 count as the same partition(in maths), here I will have to consider them different partitions. In this case we are considering it differently. I tried bruteforcing by trying to find a common pattern, and if we consider an array par[] comprising of all the partitions of 9 (the first part of the question), arranged in terms of dictionary order, par[0] = 111111111, par[1] = 11111112 par[2] - par[3] will have 2 terms that comprise of 11111121 and 1111113. If we look carefully at the last 2 digits, we will notice that they are the partitions of 3. So basically the partions starting with 1 will follow an order 1+1 (partitions of 2) + 2 (partitions of 3) + 4 (partitions of 4) and so on, increasing in powers of 2, until par[127] = 18, no. of partitions of 8. We notice that on adding them we get powers of 2. However, I seem to be stuck on calculating position 156, as par[128] = 21111111, and I am unable to move further in my method. A recurrence relation or pseudocode will be most welcome. The answer as an integer is available online, but not the algorithm. Please help me out.

Source: http://www.iarcs.org.in/inoi/2012/zio2012/zio2012-qpaper.pdf 
Solution: http://www.iarcs.org.in/inoi/2012/zio2012/zio2012-solutions.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A hint:

```
partitions of 1
1      the number itself

partitions of 2
11     1 followed by partitions of 1
2      the number itself

partitions of 3
111    1 followed by partitions of 2
12     .
21     2 followed by partitions of 1
3      the number itself

partitions of 4
1111   1 followed by partitions of 3
112    .
121    .
13     .
211    2 followed by partitions of 2
22     .
31     3 followed by partitions of 1
4      the number itself

partitions of 5
11111   1 followed by partitions of 4
1112    .
1121    .
113     .
1211    . 
122     .
131     . 
14      .
2111    2 followed by partitions of 3
212     .
221     .
23      .
311     3 followed by partitions of 2
32      .
41      4 followed by partitions of 1
5       the number itself
```